# postgres filter column if name not in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgreSQL.
I have two tables main, secondary each with 1 column

main

```
data
test1@james.com
john@gmail.com
nnn@bff.com
laura@gg.com
jamessaraha@rrr.org
...
```

secondary

```
name
james
john
```

expected output:

```
data
nnn@bff.com
laura@gg.com
```

I want to filter main (10 mil rows) using the names in secondary (40k rows), if the `name` is not in `data` (case insensitive).

Note: both tables have unique data

Comment: Before anyone offers you a query, can you include whatever you have tried already?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't have a query, I am currently doing it in python but it takes around 40 minutes to do it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a not exists condition:

```
select *
from main m
where not exists (select * 
                  from secondary s 
                  where m.data ilike '%'||s.name||'%');
```

Comment: can you please explain what `||'%'` does?

Comment: @porgrammer3124: `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL. `%` is the wildcard for LIKE in SQL. So the expression appends the wildcard to the name that should be compared. This is pretty basic SQL stuff

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wouldn't it be better to use ILIKE? and get rid of lower()?

Comment: @jjanes: true, I changed it. (Won't make a performance difference though)

Comment: Needs wild cards on both sides of the string.  For example `'james'` must cause `'test1@james.com'` to be excluded.

Comment: @MatBailie: that's not how I understood the question, but if that is desired, then you are correct.

Comment: I can see no other explanation for the example data and desired output. Your query currently returns `'test1@james.com'` but the desired output does not include it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT data
FROM main
LEFT JOIN secondary ON strpos(lower(main.data), lower(secondary.name)) > 0
WHERE secondary.name IS NULL
```